# vs2010 intellisense not all there

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I just copied over an Visual Studio 2010 source code from one SVN repository to a new repository and "checked it out". However in the new location my project's intellisense is not working as it does in it's old location.

When i open my old project this is how it looks:

[image]

The new one looks like this. I compiles and runs fine. But i've lost intellisense.

[image]

My setting are already to what [scott suggests here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/26/no-intellisense-with-vs-2010-rc-and-how-to-fix-it.aspx). What gives?

Comment: NO, it's my own version of IDisposable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen if you open a file that isn't in the project.

Close all documents and open a file from the solution explorer and see if that helps.